# Sed with variables

Tags: sed

i have a config file with this format

```
http://link:port/username/password/1234
```

Im using this code to replace the Username1/Password1 with a different Username2/Password2

```
sed -i -e 's/\/Username1\/Password1/\/Username2\/Password2/g' /etc/config.cfg
```

Now i want to make this something like

```
$UsernameOLD = Username1
$PasswordOLD = Password1

$UsernameNEW = Username2
$PasswordNEW = Password2

sed -i -e 's/\/$UsernameOLD\/$PasswordOLD/\/$UsernameNEW\/$PasswordNEW/g' /etc/config.cfg
```

Could anyone help me getting this ready ?

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: Do not use `sed` for passwords, they may look like `[/\1 &'\2 ("`.

Comment: Its okay as they are numeric/alphabetic only. But i will keep in mind if they change and i run into trouble. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i had to use double quotes instead of '

The working command looks like this:

```
UsernameOLD=MyOldUsername
PasswordOLD=MyOldPassword
UsernameNEW=MyNewUsername
PasswordNEW=MyOldUsername

sed -i -e "s/\/$UsernameOLD\/$PasswordOLD/\/$UsernameNEW\/$PasswordNEW/" /etc/config.cfg
```